# Make ms access database trusted for all users on network disc

Tags: python, vba, ms-access

I have made a GUI using python and tkinter, which allows the user to choose search criterias to be used in an MS Access query. Upon a buttonclick, the script opens Access and runs a macro which in turn launches a function that reads the user input, performs the query and prints reports. The code used to do this is:

```
objAccess = win32com.client.Dispatch("Access.application")
objAccess.Visible = False
objAccess.OpenCurrentDatabase(filepath)
objAccess.DoCmd.RunMacro("Macro1")
objAccess.Quit()
```

My problem is that I want to put the database and the python script on a network drive so that my coworkers may use the script to generate reports without having to open the database in Access (and inevitably make inadvertent changes). Whenever the script is run for the first time from someone else's PC, it will not complete, as the macros have not been enabeled from that pc. If they open the database and enable macros and make the document "trusted", the script will work fine.

What I want to know is if there is any way to enable macros permanetly for all users for that particular Access database, or if I can modify my script to check if the database has macros enabled or not, and to enable macros if they are disabled.

I know that the disabling of macros is a security measure, so I guess I may just have to ask my users to manually enable macros before running the script. Not very elegant.

Comment: why not approach this in more straightforward way? just split your DB, provide runtime fron-end to your employees. they can do whatever they want to print. loading access db from network drive might increase the load time too..

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways of enable macro permanently.

1. Trusted Location: A path/location, where stored databases are always trusted.
2. Trusted Publisher: Sign database with certification

You can set/edit them in the trust center settings in File > Options > Trust Center > Trust Center Settings.
But you have to set it up for every user/access-installation at least once.

Here is the official link from MS how to do it:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn166703.aspx

Be aware, that Microsoft does not recommend to set network pathes as trusted locations. Also, you should consider @Krish KMs comment suggestion, to create a local front end for the users. This would also need a trusted location or publisher, but not on network drive, but on a local drive.